# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 is busy

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am getting this error everytime i run the solution (20 projs). I tried to disable the UI options , resharper, deleted un used extensions etc. but still couldnt get pass this error.

I am on VS 2015 Update 2 Enterprise version
I have restarted VS several times, killed the process when i got that message and sometimes i stopped the app when i got that message.
I have also unloaded the projects that are not necessary for my task at this moment but still same problem

Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an internal operation to complete. If you regularly encounter this delay during normal usage, please report this problem to Microsoft.
[image: Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy Dialog]

Please advise if you have any solution to resolve this error.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: basically i couldnt get pass this error and run the app. thats the question. do you have any thoughts on how to resolve this.

Comment: Try restarting visual studio 2015.

Comment: @sebenalern ofcourse I have restarted VS several times., I have unloaded the projs that i wont be using at that time, I have uninstalled other components that are on like Azure, Silverlight, Resharper etc (coz i dont need them at this moment) But didnt help at all.

Comment: Is the process still running in the background? Try to close that too, if it is.

Comment: @sebenalern I am stopping the VS by ending the process.

Answer (score 25):

I had the similar issue. I upgraded a solution from vs2012.

Deleting .vs folder from solution folder did solve my issue.

Comment: This works for me also, but is reappearing again and again... Are there any details on why those files are problematic?

Comment: First, identify which projects in your solution failed to load. Inspect that project files in the windows explorer. Delete unnecessary files if you notice any. This may not be the answer you are expecting but hope it helps.

Comment: Also look at project output window for any messages or warnings, you may find the root cause.

Comment: The problem is not that projects fail to load, but that the VS hangs, thus I cannot interact with it.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Not sure, why this hidden folder started creating the problem suddenly? but after deleting it, I can see the issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I reset the iis and it worked fine.
Didnt have to unload the projects either.

start -> run -> iisreset

Answer (score 2):

There could be different reasons causing it.

I would suggest using [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check the details for all your `devenv.exe` events to identify the exact reason.

Here is a screenshot of my previous findings:
[image]

We then know some class to load is not available for the solution to load.

Comment: I followed your advice and found the offending file. Can you look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409472/microsoft-visual-studio-2019-is-busy-every-time-i-open-a-dialog-procmon-search  and suggest where I go next?

Answer (score 1):

uncheck Debug -> Options -> Enable UI debugging for XAML fixes the problem for me.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99734/visual-studio-freezes-and-shows-a-busy-notificatio.html

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issues with a couple of solutions throughout the past few months myself and I think the problem doesn't actually rest with Visual Studio and the devenv process, but rather IISExpress. Stopping the local IISExpress from running and then reloading the solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue in VS 2019. VS stuck with the busy message. I have disconnected(and then reconnect) the WIFI(internet) and the message disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens if you have more than one instance because most of the time when we installing MSSQL it asks you to configure the integration part so if each instance configure differently at the time you open SSIS to create or open a project visual studio will get confused or becomes busy to select the configuration. to solve this problem you should only activate the instance you want to work with

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that worked for me after several day of battle and trying most of these solutions was "skip the validation when opening the package" check in options->Debug->Business intelligence designer

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Quick fix:

1. Go to C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
2. Delete All files in this folder