# Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy

Tags: visual-studio-2015, solution

lately, when i open my solution in VS2015 i cannot work anymore, the VS is blocked with this message:

[image]

i can open the solution and work on it if i delete the .suo file in the .vs folder of the solution, but i would like to find a better and definitive solution.

i have noticed that i have this problem only if before closing VS i do a debug, if i do not debug anything, i can close and open the solution without any problems

edit: in safe mode it's working, but if i open in the standard mode it's still blocked on the startup

Comment: Although I have marked it as a duplicate question, its a valid issue and known bug.  Before posting a question, you should have a quick look to see if anyone else has raised this point before

Comment: in this question they answered:

Posted by Allen [MSFT] on 11/3/2015 at 10:20 AM: Thank you very much for reporting this. We have researched the root cause and have made a fix that will be provided in VS2015 Update 1. Update 1 is due out in coming weeks.

but i have the update 3 ans still i have this problem...

and in the previous question the problem was "irresponsive for 10-20 seconds", in my case i cannot open it at all, i have to kill the process from task manager and delete the .suo file

Comment: have you tried opening it in safe mode?

Comment: in safe mode it's working, but if i open in the standard mode it's still blocked on the startup

Comment: btw i had to open this post because in the old one i cannot add comments or ask something else...

Comment: if it runs in safe mode, but not normal mode, have you tried with elevated privileges \ run as admin?

Comment: i always run it as admin. and that's not working

Comment: ok, the next thing I would suggest that is attempted is an either a repair or an uninstall and then reinstal

Comment: the fact is that i have this problem only on one solution, for all the other solutions i don't have this problem. i have tried to remove mapping for the solution and download it again on a different path, but still the same problem.
i wuold prefer not to uninstall vs... too much time and i have too many solution then to reinstall...
ok btw thank you for your time

Comment: ok, so i didnt realise it was only one one solution and all your others are ok. The next thing then would be to create a new solution file and add the project to the new solution, and any other projects you need in there and test them one by one, as you add a project, close visual studio, and see what happens one by one

Comment: using this approach i was able to find the project that gave problems, now it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Excellent. Glad could be of some help.

Comment: @Deatk I know this post is older but do you recall what the actual problem was with the project? I'm having the same issues in VS 2017

Comment: Here, some posts ago, i said i was able to fix the problem, but it showed again and again...
Then I have installed a VS2015 and VS2017 on another machine, downloaded the same project and i could not see the same preoblem. So the problem was not in the project...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 is busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862214/microsoft-visual-studio-2015-is-busy)

Comment: Today I installed the updated of Visual Studio 2019 ( 16.4.7 ) . After installation of the update, every time I try to open a solution , VS reports itself as busy